# How can i get facebook sdk work with Unity3d web game?

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I have integrated facebook sdk to my unity game for android and ios. On both platform it works .

But now i turned my game to run in web player. but unfortunately i am not unable to login in facebook. I read documentation written in facebook.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/3/CUI

For that i need canvas binary url. but i dont understand which url should i write? i want steps to make my web game to work with facebook sdk.

If i am going wrong then also let me know guys.. :)).

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

For webplayer, you will be placing the yourgame.unity3d, yourgame.html file and other game related files on some kind of a webserver. The Unity Binary Url is that address where you will be placing your .unity3d file.
For testing purpose, you can have a local webserver like [Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/) and host the file there and then put something like `http://localhost/yourgamefolder/yourgame.unity3d`
and later you can replace that with the place where your game will be hosted.

Hope that helps,

Jitesh

Comment: ok @Jitesh.. i am hosting my all the file on webserver. if i find any issue after that i will call u back. Thanks.. :)

Comment: hey @jitesh.. i solved this but i have my own website in that i uploaded my game in that if i want facebook functionality. is it possible??

Comment: yes. i think its possible. you can use [facebook javascript sdk](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart/v2.0) for all the facebook related functionality and then communicate between the unity webplayer and javascript functions like show [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityWebPlayerandbrowsercommunication.html)